# issues with downloading files from server php

Tags: php

I made a script for my University project that reads files in a directory and echos them via a foreach loop, it does this as a list, so

```
"<ul>";    //this ul is outside the foreach loop
    "<li><b>".$ftype.": ".$rows."</b>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='?run=delete.$dir$rows'>Delete ".$ftype."</a></li>
            <li><a href='?run=rename.$dir$rows'>Rename ".$ftype."</a></li>
            <li><a href='?run=download.$dir$rows'>Download ".$ftype."</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>";
"</ul>";   //this ending ul tag is outside the foreach loop
```

$rows is the variable used in the foreach loop

```
foreach($getDir as $rows)
```

the $ftype is a variable set depending on whether the $rows is a dir or not

```
if (is_dir($dir.$rows){
    $ftype = "Folder";
} else {
    $ftype = "File";
}
```

This is the output of my script:

```
Folder: pics
    Delete Folder
    Rename Folder
    Download Folder
File: screenshot (4).png
    Delete File
    Rename File
    Download File
File: screenshot.png
    Delete File
    Rename File
    Download File
File: screenshot_(2).png
    Delete File
    Rename File
    Download File
File: screenshot_(3).png
    Delete File
    Rename File
    Download File
Folder: trip
    Delete Folder
    Rename Folder
    Download Folder
```

Keep it short I require_once another php file containing a switch that detects what "run" is and reacts to the results so when "run" is set to download it uses the string set to "run". To explain this easily and fast I'll give an example:

If I click on "Download File" for "File: screenshot.png" run is set to

?run=download.uploads/admin@admin.com/screenshot.png so

download.uploads/admin@admin.com/screenshot.png

the switch that I made on the other php file checks if (substr($linkchoice, 0, 8)) == "download" so if the first to the eighth character of run is equal to download then executes header("Location: $linkchoice; Content-type: application/force-download");break;

```
switch($linkchoice){
    case (substr($linkchoice, 0, 8)) == "download": 
        header("Location: $linkchoice; Content-type: application/force-download");
    break;//I have cases for the rename and delete but those aren't relevant to my problem
```

My problem is that when I click download it gives me this error:

> **Access forbidden!**
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> **Error 403**
>
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15

If anyone wants to see the code ask and I'll put it on github.

If my code is wrong please tell me and how to fix it.

Also I've tried using some other download codes which let me download the file with the given extension however when I opened them, lets say a picture it opened it in windows photo viewer but it said that windows photo viewer cannot support the file type...

Comment: What does `$linkchoice` contain and what is `admin@admin.com/screenshot.png`?

Comment: $linkchoice = $_GET['run']; and admin@admin.com is a folder inside uploads folder, screenshot.png is the file itself a picture